# CubicalTT: successor of add proof?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type

Lecture 2 of the cubical type theory lectures provide a proof of
`(suc a) + b = suc (a + b)`:

```
-- (suc a) + b = suc (a + b)
addSuc (a : nat) : (b : nat) -> Path nat (add (suc a) b) (suc (add a b)) = split
  zero -> <i> suc a 
  suc n -> <i> suc (addSuc a n @ i)
```

I'm trying to move the `(b : nat)` from the return type to the argument type, such that the declaration is now `addSuc2 (a b : nat) : Path nat ...`.

```
-- |Type checking failed: infer addSuc2
addSuc2 (a b : nat) : Path nat (add (suc a) b) (suc (add a b)) = split
  zero -> split@(nat -> Path nat (add (suc a) b) (suc (add a b))) with
            zero -> <i> suc a 
            suc b' -> <i> suc a 
  suc n -> split@(Path nat (add (suc a) b) (suc (add a b))) with
            zero -> <i> suc (addSuc a n @ i)
            suc b' -> <i> suc (addSuc a n @ i)
```

Unfortunately, this fails type checking with a cryptic `infer addSuc2`. I'm unable to deduce how to fix this. (a) How do I define `addSuc2` such that it typechecks? (b) If it is impossible to define `addSuc2`, why?

Full reproducer:

````
module addzero where
data nat = zero | suc (n : nat)

add (m : nat) : nat -> nat = split
  zero -> m
  suc n -> suc (add m n)

Path (A : U) (a b : A) : U = PathP (<_> A) a b

-- (suc a) + b = suc (a + b)
addSuc (a : nat) : (b : nat) -> Path nat (add (suc a) b) (suc (add a b)) = split
  zero -> <i> suc a 
  suc n -> <i> suc (addSuc a n @ i)

-- | This fails type checking x(
addSuc2 (a b : nat) : Path nat (add (suc a) b) (suc (add a b)) = split
  zero -> split@(nat -> Path nat (add (suc a) b) (suc (add a b))) with
            zero -> <i> suc a 
            suc b' -> <i> suc a 
  suc n -> split@(Path nat (add (suc a) b) (suc (add a b))) with
            zero -> <i> suc (addSuc a n @ i)
            suc b' -> <i> suc (addSuc a n @ i)
```
````